# Validate Value Exists in multiple columns of DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am importing a spreadsheet through an asp.net C# web application. I need to validate the results of the excel -> datatable results before I pass it to the Stored Procedure. Short if enumerating all rows of each required column to validate that there is a value does anyone have a faster solution?

Implementation of Jame's suggestion; What I ended up doing was cloning the original table which only clones the schema. I then set the columns I wanted as AllowDBNull = false. Then the last step was to do a merge inside a TryCatch statement. If the merge failed then you will get a required field validation error thrown to the user.

```
   public DataTable UploadSpreadsheetData(string tempFile)
   {
        try
        {
            __filepath = tempFile;
            this.onConnectionStringChanged();
            string _sheetname = GetSheetName();
            DataTable _importedData = ReadTable(_sheetname);
            DataTable _newTableStructure = GetClone(_importedData);
            MergeDataTables(_importedData, _newTableStructure);
            return _newTableStructure;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Connection.Close();
            this.Connection.Dispose();
            DeleteTempFile(tempFile);
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetClone(DataTable table)
    {
        DataTable _cloneTable  = table.Clone();
        _cloneTable.Columns["System Code"].AllowDBNull = false;
        return _cloneTable;
    }

    private static void MergeDataTables(DataTable _importedData, 
         DataTable _newTableStructure)
    {
        try
        {
            _newTableStructure.Merge(_importedData, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add a reference to required value structure for the 
            // end user to verify validity of the spreadsheet
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("The following 
            error was encountered while importing the spreadsheet data. {0}. 
            Please check the spreadsheet to ensure all required values are 
            present.", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Faster as in more performant I assume (as opposed to faster (easier) to write)?

Comment: Is your need to make sure values are present?  Or to prevent duplicates?

Comment: yes performant is main goal and all I need is a value in the field

Comment: I see, so in short, let's say you have DataTable tb and column 4 needs a value, you want to make sure there are no rows where column 4 is null, right?  What version of .NET?

Comment: Correct. But in the larger view more like 20 columns that every row has a value. 3.5 Framework

Comment: Okay, so in 3.5 can't take advantage of TPL for easy parallelism.  About how many rows?

Comment: Unknown at this point. That is my big fear. There has been no business requirements set around row limitations as yet.

Comment: Can you check to see if the values it gives you are blank or null (DBNull.Value)?  If null you can do the following in your DataTable:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of the columns that are "missing" are `null` (`DBNull.Value`) you can do:

```
// or whatever means you use to get your table...
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// define your columns (whether imported or manual)

// set the columns that must have a value to deny DBNull, for example if col 3 & 4:
dt.Columns[3].AllowDBNull = false;
dt.Columns[4].AllowDBNull = false;
```

Once those columns are set to `AllowDBNull = false` then you will get an exception when you set it to `false` if the data was loaded before, or you will get an exception on the `Add` of the row if the data is added after set to `false`.

So, if possible, set up your columns first, but if those are defined in the import, just set your columns to `AllowDBNull = false` in a try/catch, and if you catch an exception you know you have an issue in that column.

If the values are blank strings, this won't work of course.  But if that's what you need I can dig more...

Comment: That's actually a good suggestion. Thanks James. the update to the original post for my implementation